# storing one-to-many relationship data from form in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, one-to-many

I am new to laravel.
I got stuck here.
my model:

```
class PersonalitySliderImages extends Model
{
    public $table = "personality_slider";

    protected $fillable = [
        'image_name',
        'personality_id',
    ];

    public function personality()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('testApp\Personality');
    }

}

class Personality extends Model
{
    public $table = "personality";

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'position',
        'about',
        'message',
        'image',
        'status',
    ];

    public function personalitySliderImages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('testApp\PersonalitySliderImages');
    }
}
```

and request object as follow

```
request: ParameterBag {#45 ▼
    #parameters: array:6 [▼
      "_token" => "IDi5u03XDNhrdaCLUh2thYYcd98b8Ny8eDmyNKwr"
      "name" => "fgh"
      "position" => "fgh"
      "about" => "fg"
      "message" => "fhgfhg"
      "status" => "Deactive"
    ]
  }
files: FileBag {#48 ▼
    #parameters: array:2 [▼
      "image" => UploadedFile {#30 ▶}
      "sliderimages" => array:3 [▼
        0 => UploadedFile {#31 ▶}
        1 => UploadedFile {#32 ▶}
        2 => UploadedFile {#33 ▶}
      ]
    ]
  }
```

I need to store personality first then all the slider images in table with the personality id in it.(with relationship maintained)
If during storing personality have problem then there is no entry for sliderimages.
If the sliderimages entry have error then personality entry also been rollback.
How to approach this?

Comment: create a personality, then create all the images, then attach all images ids to `personality->images()->attach([$arrayofids]);`

Comment: @Achraf `attach()` is used to insert the records in intermediate table that joins the models. may be only in many to many relationship.

Comment: oh, my bad, he should use associate() i guess

Comment: i able to store data of personality and slider_image easily. but the problem is when i need to dependent process of storing those tables. also here the slider_image data is simply the array of names.

Comment: so your problem is that there may be some insert error during insert right?@user2536760

Comment: @user2536760 if this is the problem, you can use `DB::beginTransaction()` and than at the end of the script, if everything it's ok, do `DB::commit()`, else `DB::rollback()`